# AFNetworking Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain,

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, serialization, afnetworking

I tried all the way, but getting error

> NSLocalizedDescription=**Request failed: bad request (400)**,
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<48545450 20343030
>   0a4d6973 73696e67 20706172 616d6574 65723a20 27726566 6572656e
>   636527>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a81aa80 {Error
>   Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request
>   failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain"
>   UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: https:///mobile/v1/document/get } {
>   status code: 400, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, private";
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Sun, 29 May 2016 20:31:44 GMT";
>       Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
>       "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains";
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
>       "X-Exception-Class" = "PM\PFTAPIBundle\Exception\MissingAPIParameterException";
>       "X-Exception-Message" = "Missing parameter: 'reference'";
>       "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
>       "X-Processing-Time" = "906.5ms"; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https:///api/mobile/v1/document/get,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type:
>   text/plain, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<48545450
>   20343030 0a4d6973 73696e67 20706172 616d6574 65723a20 27726566
>   6572656e 636527>}}}  Request failed: bad request (400)

```
- (void)postResource:(NSString*)resource queryString:(NSDictionary*)queryString withCompletionHander:(CompletionHandlerBlock)completionHandler
{

NSString *qs = [DictionaryUtils convertDictToJSONString:queryString];

//    self.sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
//    self.sessionManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];//[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

//    [self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PLSID %@",sessionID] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
resource = [[self.sessionManager.baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"document/get"] absoluteString];

NSURL *base = [NSURL URLWithString:resource];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:base
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                    timeoutInterval:60.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:mACCEPTVALUE forHTTPHeaderField:mCONTENTTYPELABEL];
if ([[[UserDetails sharedInstance]getUserDetails]objectForKey:mSESSIONIDKEY]) {
    NSString *headerField = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",mSOURCEPLSID,sessionID];
    [theRequest setValue:headerField forHTTPHeaderField:mSOURCEIDENTIFIERHEADER];
}
if(qs != nil) {
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[qs dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}


NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.sessionManager dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    //
    NSLog(@"responseObject %@", responseObject);
    NSLog(@"%@ \n%@",error, [error localizedDescription]); //{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4}}}
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

}

When I test the **api** using postman and passing the param in `Body` as ***raw*** data `{"reference":{"Id":"User","documentId":"56e0"}}` [***NOTE: NOT in*** x-www-form-urlencoded or form-data]. *`It works and getting response with data.`*

[image]

Comment: You can see that the postman screenshot shows the request is text/json, not text/plain.

Comment: @Avi Thanks, But I am setting the content type  [theRequest setValue:mACCEPTVALUE forHTTPHeaderField:mCONTENTTYPELABEL]; where mACCEPTValUE is text/json

Comment: So your question is really how to get AF to send your request as `text/json`, because the error you posted clearly shows that it isn't.

Comment: @Avi Yes Avi. I am passing parameter {"reference":{"sheetId":"User","documentId":"56e02ac1f045d90f508b45fb"}} as raw data

Comment: I see where it's going wrong.  It's not the request that's wrong, it's the response.  You are expecting a JSON response, but you're getting a 400 response which includes text explaining the error.  If you decode the returned data, you get `HTTP 400
Missing parameter: 'reference'`.

Comment: @Avi Absolutely right. When I add the line self.sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFHttpRequestSerializer serializer]; then i get "X-Exception-Message" = "Failed to decode JSON post-data: No error";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113279/discussion-between-praveen-k-and-avi).

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using AFNetworking, try accepting content types explicitly

```
let serviceManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
serviceManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects: "text/plain", "text/html", "application/json", "audio/wav", "application/octet-stream", "text/javascript") as? Set
```

This worked for me

Comment: A typo found, it should be `application/octet-stream`. It take a few time to figure out it...